# Average Number of Sutures per E.R. visit

Tags: surgery, statistics, emergency, sutures, abscess-lesions

I'm trying to gather data for a bioengineering project, but I'm finding difficulty locating the statistic of the average number of sutures per visit, for E.R.'s. Does anyone know how to find this data? I've tried Google Scholar to look for studies, but couldn't find anything (or my research skills are rather poor...).

Comment: I seriously doubt that anyone tracks such data. I can't imagine any practical use for it. Be that as it may, the average number of sutures per what? Per patient? Per day? Per doctor?

Comment: per E.R. visit as it says in the title